# How to install download-command plugin in gerrit for usage with Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gerrit, intellij-plugin

I want to use gerrit v2.16.7 with the gerrit plugin for IntelliJ IDEA.

The errorlog in IDEA says that I need a download-commands plugin. How do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the correct version of the download-commands plugin with the configurator from gerrit:

```
java -jar gerrit.war init -d {path to gerrit home e.g. ../} --install-plugin=download-commands
```

All the options should be by default, what you already configured except the option to install download-commands.

[Source](https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-intellij-plugin#error-message-when-loading-changes-sslexception-received-fatal-alert-bad_record_mac)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install the latest version of download-commands plugin on your Gerrit v2.16.7 is:

- ssh to your Gerrit server
- change your current directory to the `$GERRIT_SITE/plugins`
- run `curl -O https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Gerrit/job/Gerrit-bazel-stable-2.16/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/gerrit/bazel-bin/plugins/download-commands/download-commands.jar`

Gerrit will automatically detect the new plugin and load it without any downtime.